# regex php obfuscation video url

Tags: php

Hello I'm beginner for PHP. 
I read this article http://flowplayer.blacktrash.org/secure-http.html 
and I don't understand the htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ video.php?h=$1&t=$2&v=$3
```

and this php file

```
$hash = $_GET['h'];
$streamname = $_GET['v'];
$timestamp = $_GET['t'];
```

cannot understand How does this RegEx working? what is h=$1 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an Apache/Regex question rather than PHP.

To answer the question, inside regexes *parentheses* "capture" what is matched inside. The *$1, $2, $3* are replaced with what was captured with the parentheses. In your example `(.*)` will match any character any number of times.

For example, if `food/fruit/apples` was supplied it would be rewritten (by Apache) to `video.php?h=food&t=fruit&v=apples`. Then when PHP receives the request it will pull the GET parameters of *h,t,v* and assign them to variables.

```
$hash = $_GET['h'];       // value: "food"
$timestamp = $_GET['t'];  // value: "fruit"
$streamname = $_GET['v']; // value: "apples"
```